# Phonegap and Bootstrap.css - display all list items in a list-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I am writing a Phonegap app that uses Bootstrap.css.  I'm creating a list-group with what could be a large number of entries in this fashion:

```
<div class="list-specs">
    <ul class="list-group list-specs" id="books-list">
        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Title: Catch-22</strong><p>Author: Joseph Heller</p></li>
        <li ... many more li's>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The class list-specs is defined as follows.  I applied it to both the div and the ul because I wasn't sure which should get it.  The same behavior is seen when applied to only one of either:
    .list-specs {
        height:1500px;
        overflow-y:auto;
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }

When I view the page in a browser, all entries are displayed.  However, when the page is rendered in PhoneGap, only the first 8 or so entries are displayed.  The remainder are cut off from the bottom of the page.

What do I have to do to have the page scroll and include all of the li entries?